# Overriding a grandparent's virtual method that was called in grandparent's constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm having trouble on my c++ code ..

```
class GrandParent {
public:
    GrandParent() 
    { 
        printMe(); 
    }

    virtual void printMe() 
    {
        std::cout << "GrandParent: printme" << std::endl;
    }
}

class Parent : public GrandParent {
public:
    Parent(){}
    virtual void printMe()
    {
         std::cout << "Parent: printMe!" << std::endl;
    }
}

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(){}

    void printMe()
    {
         std::cout << "Child: printMe!" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
     Child *p = new Child();
     delete p;
}
```

When I run this code, it prints "GrandParent: printMe".
my goal is to print "Child: printMe!". Is there something wrong in overriding printMe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible. At the time of `GrandParent`'s constructor, the only part of the `Child` object that has been constructed and initialized is the `GrandParent` part - including the vtable. That is, when you call `printMe()`, the entry will be `GrandParent`'s. It's only after `Child` gets constructed that the vtable entry for `printMe()` gets updated to point to `Child::printMe`.

Note that it's good that C++ works like this. If `Child::printMe` *had* been the one called, then you'd be calling a member function on a not-yet-constructed object. Nothing good can come of that.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: That's how C++ works.

When a virtual method is called from the constructor, not the method of the runtime class is used. Instead the method of the compile time class is used.

But there might be an escape using the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582239/avoiding-virtual-methods-in-constructor):

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Base
{
protected:
    Base()
    {
        T::printMe();
    }
};

class GrandParent : Base<GrandParent>
{
public:
    GrandParent()
        : Base<GrandParent>()
    {}
    static void printMe()
    {
        std::cout << "GrandParent: printMe!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Parent : public GrandParent, public Base<Parent>
{
public:
    Parent()
    {}
    static void printMe()
    {
        std::cout << "Parent: printMe!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent, public Base<Child>
{
public:
    Child()
    {}
    static void printMe()
    {
        std::cout << "Child: printMe!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    GrandParent a;
    std::cout << "..." << std::endl;
    Parent b;
    std::cout << "..." << std::endl;
    Child c;
    std::cout << "..." << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
GrandParent: printMe!
...
GrandParent: printMe!
Parent: printMe!
...
GrandParent: printMe!
Parent: printMe!
Child: printMe!
...
```

But yeah, then you have to deal with static methods **and** multiple inheritence.